# Swiftui. Combine transform Publisher to object

Tags: swift, publish-subscribe, reactive, combine

I don't have much skill in reactive programming with Swift and I don't know how I can subscribe to a service that is a publisher and how to transform the output to an object.

The code is:

sorry, where?

the complete code is this:

```
@Published var authResponse: Bool = false
let fireStoreDBService: FirestoreDbServiceProtocol = FirestoreDBService(). //return AnyPublishers

func authentication(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {
      
    return fireStoreDBService.authentication(email: email, password: password)
        .map{ auth -> Bool in
            
            self.authResponse = auth
            return self.authResponse
            
        }
}
```

**Error:**
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>, Bool>' to return type 'Bool'

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to return the property (self.authResponse) from the closure in the first place?

Comment: sorry, where? 

the complete code is this: 

let fireStoreDBService: FirestoreDbServiceProtocol = FirestoreDBService(). //return AnyPublishers
    
    @Published var authResponse: Bool = false

    func authentication(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {
          
        return fireStoreDBService.authentication(email: email, password: password)
            .map{ auth -> Bool in
                
                self.authResponse = auth
                return self.authResponse
                
            }
    }

Comment: I meant in the map function. I think you should use .sink instead of .map